# Trying to reload stylesheet in Dreamweaver/Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, dreamweaver

Using a template in Dreamweaver and Chrome for preview- every time I refresh the page in Chrome and go back to Dreamweaver it gives me the error that the style sheet has been changed outside of Dw(CS4). now it never changes anything- but you could imagine a window popping up that you cant just close by hitting enter come up.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190227/dreamweaver-falsely-prompting-about-modified-files

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting the option "Preview Using Temporary File" in Dreamweaver under Edit >> Preferences >> Preview in Browser will do you any good.