# Dreamweaver falsely prompting about modified files

Tags: dreamweaver, reload, prompt

I use Dreamweaver 8 at work, and recently I've been having an issue with open files. When I move focus away from Dreamweaver to another piece of software (usually firefox for testing the results of uploaded files), and then move back to Dreamweaver I get a prompt saying: "This file has been modified outside of Dreamweaver. Do you want to reload it".

Edit: this is for every single file I have open in Dreamweaver so is quite unbearable!

Clicking yes or no both show exactly the same page! Nothing's changed, and nothing should have!

Any ideas why this might be happening? It's causing some issues because I work with another developer at work and I don't want my work overwriting. I assure you that he's not working on any of the same files or anything, and we've worked together for months and this has never happened before.

I'm very well aware that I can turn this prompt off, but in cases where files **have** actually changed, I'd want to be prompted.

I know Dreamweaver 8 is a joke.. but it's what we've got, and it's been fine up until now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: We are having exactly the same problem with CS 5. It only happens when working on files that reside on our shared network drive.

Comment: It still exists in Dreamweaver CC.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior exists in CS5 too, so I'm pretty sure it is a bug.  Are you working off a shared network drive?

Comment: I am yeah, it's bizarre. Works fine on my colleague's computer.

Comment: Okay.  It is something about the share being refreshed by the OS that causes this but I've really been able to pinpoint it further.  As I said, I think it's mostly a DW bug as the behavior exists even in the current versions